# How to retrive full name(with space between two word) in php?

Tags: php

Here i am trying to store data into database,It will work successful but when i am seen into database then for Assigned To it will only store first name for example, Value of assign_to=Trilok Dethariya, then in database it will only store Trilok for assign_to field,How can i store full name into it.

```
<label>Assigned To</label>
<?php 
    $sqll="SELECT Full_name FROM user_master where Role='Project Manager'";
    $rows = $conn->query($sqll);

    echo "<select class='form-control' name='assign_to'>";
    echo "<option value=''>Select One</option>";  

    while($row= $rows->fetch_assoc() ) 
    {
        echo "<option value=".$row['Full_name'].">".$row['Full_name']."</option>";     
    }
    echo "</select>"; 

?>

</div>
</div> 
</form>
<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")  
    {
        $assign_to = (filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'assign_to'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must quote attribute values in html:

```
echo "<option value='".$row['Full_name']."'>".$row['Full_name']."</option>";
```

With string interpolation this can be written cleaner as

```
echo "<option value='{$row['Full_name']}'>{$row['Full_name']}</option>";
```

Better yet, normalize your data, and use IDs instead of names:

```
$sqll="SELECT ID, Full_name FROM user_master where Role='Project Manager'";

...

while($row= $rows->fetch_assoc() ) 
{
    echo "<option value='{$row['ID']}'>{$row['Full_name']}</option>";     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If You wont Full Name Using this logic than You need to some change here

You Have to replace space to underscore between first name and last name, And Where you get value there You have to replace underscore to space.
Change Here

```
 while($row= $rows->fetch_assoc() ) 
    {
        echo "<option value=".str_replace(' ', '_', $row['Full_name']).">".$row['Full_name']."</option>";     
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you only post the first row into the Database. Maybe create and extra query / or update your own.